# Adding build description column to a Jenkins view using DSL

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jobs, configure

I have a rather extensive Job DSL script defined and I'd like a way to add the 'build description' column to the custom views this Job DSL script generates. Is there a way to jump out into a configure block to add the 'build description' column programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got the question right, but to add a description you need to use the following:

```
job('JobName') {
     ...
     listView('project-name') {
        description('here goes the description')
        ....
     }
     ...
}
```

If the description need to be provided dynamically in the seed job, then you can define a parameter in the Seed job and then pass the value of this parameter to the description method:

```
/* DESCRIPTION is a build parameter supplied to this Seed job, 
   value of which to be supplied while running the 
   seed job "with parameters"    
*/
def desc = DESCRIPTION;

job('JobName') {
     ...
     listView('project-name') {
        description(desc)
        ....
     }
     ...
}
```